# How to set the Quota (Size) for Azure FileShare using PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, azure, fileshare

```
$ctx=New-AzureStorageContext <accountname> <accountkey>


$s = New-AzureStorageShare <accountname> -Context $ctx
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this cmdlet Arun: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/storage/azure.storage/v2.1.0/set-azurestoragesharequota

```
Set-AzureStorageShareQuota -ShareName "ContosoShare01" -Quota 1024
```

Thanks, Tim.